# How to change xaxis labels styling on column chart on apexcharts?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

How to change x-axis labels background-colors, border's width, and radius?

I'm using this configuration:

```
const options = {
   ...
    xaxis: {
      categories: props.dataX,
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: "14px",
          colors: "red",
          backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
          cssClass: "chart-label-x",
        },
      },
      axisTicks: { show: false },
    },
    ...
    },
  };
```

Current chart design :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDMks.png)

Targeted Chart Design:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJTcf.png)

Language stacks using:

- React.js
- Material-UI

Note:
Adding external css class (cssClass: "chart-label-x") and defining properties in external css style file (styles.css) didn't help.

```
.chart-label-x {
  border-style: solid;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background: blue;
  color: yellow;
}
```

Any help please ?

change xaxis labels styling on column chart on apexcharts

Answer (score 1):

Your customized style need to be in the component where you use the Apexchart. Additionally, you need to use the `!important`

```
.chart-label-x {
  border-style: solid !important;
  border: 5px solid red !important;
  background: blue !important;
  color: yellow !important;
}
```